# Change background when you click a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I basically want for the visitor to be able to click on a picture and for the background to change :

```
<div class="box1">     
    <ul id="bgbg">
       <li id="bg1"><a href="#"></a> </li>
       <li id="bg2"><a href="#"></a> </li>
       <li id="bg3"><a href="#"></a> </li>    
</ul> </div>


$(document).ready(function() { 
   $( "#bgbg > li" ).click(function() {
      $( 'body' ).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3');
      $( 'body' ).addClass( $(this).attr('id') );
   });
});
```

But it's not working ...

**EDIT :** It was due to the jQuery’s Compatibility Mode of wordpress  -  [Link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/?imob=b&utm_expid=3606929-106.UePdqd0XSL687behGg-9FA.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fpremium.wpmudev.org%2Fblog%2Freplacing-default-wordpress-scripts%2F%3Fimob%3Db)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery( "#bgbg > li" ).click(function() {
      jQuery( 'body' ).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3');
      jQuery( 'body' ).addClass( jQuery(this).attr('id') );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  
  $( "#bgbg > li" ).click(function() {
      $( 'body' ).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3');
      $( 'body' ).addClass($(this).attr('id')) ;
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
});
```

```css
#bg1{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
}


#bg2{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:url('http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Big-Waves-Fantasy-Image-HD.jpg');
background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
}


#bg3{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/12/19/2429637D00000578-0-image-a-284_1419003100839.jpg');
background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
}

.bg1{
background:url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
}


.bg2{
background:url('http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Big-Waves-Fantasy-Image-HD.jpg');
}


.bg3{
background:url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/12/19/2429637D00000578-0-image-a-284_1419003100839.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="box1">     
    <ul id="bgbg">
       <li id="bg1"><a href="#"></a> </li>
       <li id="bg2"><a href="#"></a> </li>
       <li id="bg3"><a href="#"></a> </li>    
</ul> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the problem, it only worked when I added "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"  but shouldn't that already be in the header of the site?  

I think it's using jquery 1.11.2

Answer (score 1):

I belive you have mistake in selector. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $( ".box1 li" ).click(function() { //check selector
      $( 'body' ).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3');
      $( 'body' ).addClass( $(this).attr('id') );
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the problem, it only worked when I added "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 but shouldn't that already be in the header of the site? I think it's using jquery 1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

You are have a mistake in select a element:
Use the way i use in this code (You can use this code also to add att ):

```
    <script>
          $('your element #id or .class or name').attr('att name','value');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did something similar recently and went with this approach

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect bg-btn" data-img="bg1.jpg">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect bg-btn" data-img="bg2.jpg">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect bg-btn" data-img="bg3.jpg">3</button>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bg-btn').click(function(){
        var img = 'images/' + $(this).data('img');
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ img + ')');
        console.log(img);
    });
});
```

Might help you out.